# How to change application's fonts from settings?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, fonts

I know that from the settings one can change the size of the fonts appearing on his device, however I can't see this change in my app. Is there a way to enable that for my app as well? Do I have to set something in info.plist or write extra lines of code? I couldn't find the answer on this particular issue. Only custom fonts were proposed

Thx!

Comment: Do you mean _dynamic type_ (https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/typography/) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use Dynamic Type you will have to use one of the font styles: 
`.headline`, `.subheadline`, `.body`, `.footnote`, `.caption1`, `caption2`.

and then use:

```
label.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .headline)
label.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
```

Check out Apple's documentation regarding [Scaling Fonts Automatically](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uifont/scaling_fonts_automatically).